# How to subclass an inner (static) class in Rhino?

Tags: java, javascript, subclass, rhino, inner-classes

I'm trying to subclass an inner class (defined in Java) in Rhino, and I can't seem to make it work.

I've got some compiled Java code (which I essentially can't change) that has an inner abstract class:

```
package mypackage;
class MyClass {
  abstract static class MyInnerClass {
    abstract void print(String s);
  }
}
```

From Rhino, I can see it just fine:

```
js> Packages.mypackage.MyClass.MyInnerClass
[JavaClass mypackage.MyClass$MyInnerClass]
```

But I can't figure out how to subclass it.  I figured something like this would work, since I do it for non-inner classes:

```
var a = new JavaAdapter(Packages.mypackage.MyClass.MyInnerClass, {
  print: function(s) { print("s=" + s); },
});
```

Not only does it not work, Rhino itself quits, and gives me quite the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class adapter1 cannot access its superclass mypackage.MyClass$MyInnerClass
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:676)
at org.mozilla.javascript.DefiningClassLoader.defineClass(DefiningClassLoader.java:62)
    ...
```

Am I doing it wrong?  Any ideas?

EDIT: Oh, I just realized that MyClass isn't declared "public".  Could that be it?

Comment: well, make it public and get back to us :-)

Comment: Probably yes, depending on where you are trying to subclass, you need to make it public.

Answer (score 2):

The inner class must be public.

```
package org.example;

public class Foo
{
    public abstract static class MyInnerClass
    {
        abstract void print(String s);
    }

    public void pr()
    {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

**First test**: Subclass and instantiate the outer `Foo` class:

```
$ java -classpath $PWD:/usr/share/java/js.jar:/usr/share/java/jline.jar:. org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
Rhino 1.7 release 2 2010 01 20
js> var a = new JavaAdapter(Packages.org.example.Foo, {
  >   pr: function() { print("jsfoo"); },
  > });
js> a.pr();
jsfoo
```

**Second test**: Subclass and instantiate the inner class:

```
js> var b = new JavaAdapter(Packages.org.example.Foo.MyInnerClass, {
  >   print: function(s) { print("Inner: " + s); },
  > });
js> b.print("one");
Inner: one
undefined
```

**Note**: If I change the inner class not to be public, I get the exact same error you reported.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's visibility is package private you may only create sub class of it in same package, maybe that's the problem?